# JToggleButton.One selected, others deselected

Tags: java, swing, jtogglebutton

So I have three buttons, let's say 1, 2 and 3.
I want, when I click button1, button2 and button3 to be deselected. After, when I click button2, I want button1 and button3 to be deselected. Same for button3.

Basically, when I click one button, I want the other 2 to be deselected. So far I have the following code but I'm stuck somewhere and I can't see the mistake.

```
if(smallbuttonpage1.isSelected()){
    normalbuttonpage1.setSelected(false);
    bigbuttonpage1.setSelected(false);
    textpage1.setFont(new Font("ComicSansMS", Font.PLAIN, 8));
}
if(normalbuttonpage1.isSelected()){
    smallbuttonpage1.setSelected(false);
    bigbuttonpage1.setSelected(false);
    textpage1.setFont(new Font("ComicSansMS", Font.PLAIN, 12));
}
if(bigbuttonpage1.isSelected()){
    smallbuttonpage1.setSelected(false);
    normalbuttonpage1.setSelected(false);
    textpage1.setFont(new Font("ComicSansMS", Font.PLAIN, 20));
}
```

Comment: can you describe what being "stuck" means, what exactly is going wrong? i would also recommend JRadioButton within a button group for this.

Comment: Stuck as in, when I click button2 when button1 is selected, button1 does not isSelected(false).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply add all buttons to a newly created `ButtonGroup`. This automatically takes care for deselecting the other buttons.

Have a look into the Swing tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end. I used hasFocus() instead of isSelected() and it works just fine, hope it helps anyone in the future.

Comment: No, don't. This is a horrible idea.  You have no means to guarantee that the focus will remain with the button, also you will have no means to inspect the result in the future...